Only one FTP query to get directory files and metadata
I'm working on a project that needs solid performance.
I need to analyze the contents of an FTP folder (and its sub-folders) with a single FTP request (to avoid making a call per file, which I could do with ftp_host.stat(file_path)).
For each folder, I need to retrieve :

The file/folder name (and whether it's a folder or a file)
File size
The file's last modification date

I'm working with ftputil in Python. The framework I'm working in requires this information (I can't use download_if_newer()). I tried with the code:
ftp_host._dir(folder)

This code returns almost everything I need in this line:
-rw-r--r-- 1 test ftpusers 37 Aug 13 09:37 fruits.csv

who gives me this information:

leading - indicates that it's a file (d for directory)
37 is the size
and fruits.csv is the name

However, the date is incomplete: I only get Aug 13 09:37. The year is missing.
Is there a solution for retrieving the year as well?

ftputil author here :-) The timestamps in the stat and lstat results are as accurate as the values in the directory listings retrieved from the server. For entries older than a year this would mean accurate to a day. In the stat/lstat return value, the attribute _st_mtime_precision contains the precision in seconds.

The ftputil library doesn't allow you to retrieve the exact date if the year doesn't correspond to the current year.

_dir()
stat()
path.getmtime()
are all affected by this problem.

If you can use ftplib, you can use this code to obtain the files and their metadata:
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP(hostname, username, password)

entries = session.mlsd("", ["Modify", "Type", "Size"])

# or if you're using ftputil :
# entries = ftp_host._session.mlsd("", ["Modify", "Type", "Size"])
for x in entries:
    print(x)

prints
('file.csv', {'modify': '20240813125957', 'size': '855', 'type': 'file'})
('folder_name', {'modify': '20240813130350', 'type': 'dir'})
('old_file.csv', {'modify': '20231109154538', 'size': '1747142067', 'type': 'file'})

RFC 3659 section 7.2 lists the facts added here as parameters to session.mlsd

ftputil author here :-) In an FTPHost instance, you can access the underlying ftplib.FTP (or other factory you passed as session_factory) object with ftp_host._session, so you could call ftp_host._session.mlsd. Strictly speaking, this is a private API, but it has been there for about 20 years and I don't expect that to change. Note that the results from the mlsd call won't update the stat cache that is used by stat/lstat/getmtime etc.

Many thanks @sschwarzer for this very interesting addition (and for the library which, apart from this case, is very useful and provides a very coherent high-level interface).
